# How can I divide a USB storage device into two partitions and make one autorun a program?

Tags: windows-7, usb, autorun

I'm running Windows 7 and want to make my USB storage device run Keepass when I plug it in.  I also want to use the remainder of the storage as a directory without all of the Keepass program files inside. Is this possible?

Comment: If you get you computer to auto-run programs form a usb-storage whenever it is plugged in, you will be making your system vulnerable to attack.

Comment: As @richard implied, most Windows machines now have autorun turned *off* for security.

Answer (score 0):

Eisst GhostPens do that by faking an optical drive and having a second partition with data. AFAIK you cannot do that unless you reprogram the controller (see BadUsb). So the easy answer is no. The hard one is check if your usb drive can be reprogrammed.